# Checkmark in selected UITableViewCell also showing on non-selected cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

**heres my code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. any suggestion or help on how to fix this please.. the problem is  when i clicked the cell many cell will have checkmark ....My plan is when i clicked one cell only that cell will have Checkmark**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)thetableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newindexPath {

  [thetableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[thetableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
                              animated:true];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [thetableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newindexPath];

  if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

  } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }
}
```

**and heres the code in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(nullable PFObject *)object {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"attendance";
  UITableViewCell *cell =
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  UILabel *student_lastname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  UILabel *student_firstname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
  UILabel *student_midname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

  student_lastname.text = object[@"Last_Name"];
  student_firstname.text = object[@"First_Name"];
  student_midname.text = object[@"Middle_Name"];

  UILabel *studentNum = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
  studentNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: **any suggestion please**

Comment: what is the issue you are facing, not at all clear from your question. Please elaborate

Comment: You should add more detail about the specific problem you are having and what you want to achieve. Simply pasting in code here and asking someone to fix it for you won't lead to answers. Specify the problem, what you have tried and what errors you are facing and someone might be able to help.

Comment: if i click cell it will have checkmark and that is good... but the error is if i look or go down , other cell has checkmark also even i did not clicked..  @GurtejSingh

Comment: help me please i want to finish this because this is my thesis :-(

Comment: see my answer below and update your question so that everyone understands what you need. Accept it as a valid answer if it solves your problem (click the tick mark below the voting buttons). Thanks

Comment: @Mike well did it work?

Comment: @GurtejSingh it work but i want is the checkmark will stay when i click other cell ... if i click the cell that has checkmark,, checkmark will gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fan of either answer provided. Apple's UITableView implementation **forces** you into MVC (model-view-controller). Cell views, since they can be reused, should never store state, which is what you're doing relying on cell.selected. All answers above will fail if there are more cells than fit on screen, since they will be reused.

Given that you already have an object to store data such as "Last_Name", etc. you should also store @"Selected" as well.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(nullable PFObject *)object {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"attendance";
  UITableViewCell *cell =
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  UILabel *student_lastname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  UILabel *student_firstname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
  UILabel *student_midname = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

  student_lastname.text = object[@"Last_Name"];
  student_firstname.text = object[@"First_Name"];
  student_midname.text = object[@"Middle_Name"];

  NSNumber *selectedVal = object[@"Selected"];
  if (selectedVal && [selectedVal boolValue]) {
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  } else {
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }
  UILabel *studentNum = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
  studentNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}
```

Then, in didSelect, you change the state of the cell and force a reload (of that cell only, if appropriate).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)thetableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newindexPath {

  NSNumber *selectedVal = object[@"Selected"];
  BOOL selected = selectedVal ? ![selectedVal boolValue] : YES;
  object[@"Selected"] = @(selected);
  [thetableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newindexPath] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Comment: sir thank you so much !!!! it so great ... Amazing ....!!!! thank you so much IDOL!!! BIG CHECK TO YOU!!!! :-) :-)

Comment: sir @Todd Anderson can i get your email...or can i add you in fb?? for additional question base on my problem ...

Comment: I added contact info to my profile - feel free to reach out to me. If the question is broadly helpful write a stackoverflow question first, then ping me and I'll try my best to answer on here

Comment: sir @Todd Anderson can you help me ... if I click the button "save" all the cell that has checkmark will have plus 1 to column "present" at parse and all the non checkmark will have plus 1 to column "absent" at parse. the tableview is navigation tableview and i put "save "... thanks for advance sir...

Comment: I try to do that ..my problem is if I click the button only the last cell I clicked will have plus 1 to absent or present column in parse.. @Todd Anderson

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the issue.  Can you post or send source code that shows issues.  I don't understand what "absent" means.  This might be an issue related to changing your Parse datamodel and not related to the table itself.  Debug statements will help reveal the issue.

Comment: sir @Todd Anderson i post below the codes. help me please

Answer (score 1):

So, I am assuming that you only want to show a checkmark if the cell is selected. Recommend you to update your question please.

The problem happens because your cells are being re-used when you scroll and you need to first set the accessory type accordingly in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
if ([cell isSelected])
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

This is to ensure that whenever a cell is reused, you make sure that it does not have any checkmark if its not selected, and show a checkmark if selected.

Next use the following two methods to set the checkmark and remove it when the cell is unselected/selected like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Also, you should not call `[thetableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[thetableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:true];` This method is automatically called in your case.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: sir my plan is the checkmark will stay .. for example i clicked the cell it will have checkmark then if i clicked it again the checkmark will gone... if i did not click again the cell checkmark will stay there even i click other cell .. the checkmark will gone if i click it again..how i can do that ..

Comment: And this is the exact reason why you should explain your question better in the very first time.

Comment: sorry :-) 
   give me some code for it


my plan is when the cell has checkmark i will put a number on a cell label . #1 - mean the student is present ...#0 mean that the student is absent .. and it will automatically go to parse for update on student